# JSP page reload problem

Tags: jsp, reload

I have a hyperlink on one page say results.jsp. When I click on the link, it goes to another page say show_article.jsp with the path parameter appended to the url. On this page I read the text file with using the path passed in the url and display this file as a string with <%= stringName %> on the webpage.

Now when I go back to results.jsp page and click on the hyperlink again or reload show_article.jsp, it displays previous string concatenated with the new text string read on show_article.jsp page.

can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you please post the code that sends the parameter to the next page? How is the path received, is it via a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code snippet which goes to show_article.jsp originalQuery is a string with spaces and path is a string that contains path of the text document whose contents are to be shown.

```
<% ... link = "show_article.jsp?query="+ originalQuery.replace(" ", "+") + "&path=" + path;%>
<a href=<%=link%>> Document Name </a>
```

After clicking on Document Name first I see "Document Contents". Then when I refresh the page I see "Document Contents Document Contents"